# Listview data model updated but items not displaying

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have searched these forums for nearly 3 hours and seen several similar questions but none of the answers works for me.

I have a single Activity, with several card views. One of the card views has a Spinner with string values and a very simple ListView.  The user selects a value from the Spinner, between 1 and 12.  The ListView should then display a number of strings equal to the value selected, based on the position in the spinner list. For example, user selects 2nd item in spinner list and the ListView displays 2 strings. I have a custom adapter on the listview.  The ListView itself initially displays a single row, which is correct.  However, after the user selects a value from the spinner, the listview is not displaying the extra rows, it still only displays one row.  The data for the ListView comes from an ArrayList.  I have checked the data model of the adapter after the user selects a value and it has the correct number of entries, as does the ArrayList itself, yet no matter what I try the ListView itself still only display the first row.  I have tried NotifyDataSetChanged and every variation of Invalidate without success.

The various code samples:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (parent == spDoseFrequency){
        Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        rebuildReminderTimesList(position + 1);
    }
}

private void rebuildReminderTimesList(int numberOfTimes){
    Toast.makeText(this,"yup",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //reset selected item to position 1
    myApp.iSelectedReminderTimeIndex = 0;

    //clear array and list, then rebuild with hourly timeslots
    iarrTimes = new int[numberOfTimes][2];
    liReminderTimes.clear();
    int startTime = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++){
        iarrTimes[i][0] = startTime + i;
        iarrTimes[i][1] = 0;
        liReminderTimes.add(pad(startTime + i) + ":00");
    }
    //refresh the listview
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ReminderListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

List<String> liTimes;
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater inf;

public ReminderListAdapter(Context ctx, List<String> liTimes) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.reminder_time_listview, liTimes);
    this.liTimes = liTimes;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    inf = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
}

public void setLiTimes(List<String> liTimes){
    this.liTimes = liTimes;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (view == null){
        view = inf.inflate(R.layout.reminder_time_listview,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.sTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.sTime.setText(liTimes.get(position));
    return view;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView sTime;
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated as this is driving me crazy.

Quick update to this question: I have just tested supplying the initial list more than one value but even then it only displays the first item. Is there perhaps a problem with using ListView inside a CardView object? All my other cards work fine, only the ListView one fails to display properly.

Also, I have tried amending the code so that instead of changing the number of elements in the list, it just changes the text in the string of the first element and this works fine.  So the notifyDataSetChanged appears to be working, but it just won't display more than one item.  A quick check of the Adapter.getCount() method also gives the correct number of elements back, but won't display them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I had several CardView objects inside a LinearLayout, which itself was inside a ScrollView.  As soon as I removed the ScrollView, the List inside the Card displayed properly.  This has unfortunately created another problem in that I can no longer scroll the page to see later cards, which I have not yet found a solution for, but that is a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of folks forget to do the `notifyDataSetChanged()` call, but you've got that. Are you using a custom adapter? If so, that makes this sound like an issue with one or more of the adapter's methods. In particular, it sounds like `getCount` or `getView` might not be returning what they should be. That could either be because of a flawed logic issue, the underlying data source isn't being updated correctly, or the underlying data source isn't the same object you think it is. Without seeing your adapter though, it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: Initially I tried using a simple standard adapter, rather than a customised one because it only needs to display a string.  This had the same propblem.  I then rebuilt it using a custom adapter but to no avail.  Custom adapter code now added to post.  I also tried first extending BaseAdapter, then later ArrayAdapter.